# Repeating a google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I was smart enough to figure out the script to get it so column E updates every time column D changes.

```
function onEdit(e){
if(e.range.columnStart > 4 || e.range.rowStart !=3 ) return;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
ss.getRange("E3").setValue(ss.getRange("E3").getValue()+1); 
}
```

NOW - I need to repeat this function on every row so when column D5 is changed E5 is updated, column D6 changes E6, so on.

I have tried to do "reiterate" scripts but I keep running into the problem where either I change cell D3 and it updates the ENTIRE E column. Or every change in column D changes only the first cell in column E

Comment: This function only runs on user Edits not everytime a column changes.

Comment: You need to make this (getRange("E3")) dynamic and get the working cell using your "e" parm. it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this...

```
function onEdit(e){
if(e.range.columnStart != 4 ||  e.range.rowStart < 3) return;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
var columnDValue = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).getValue();
if (typeof columnDValue == "number"){
  ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).setValue(columnDValue + 1);
  } 
}
```

I also changed e.range.columnStart > 4 to e.range.columnStart != 4, because in first case changes in cell A5 (for example) can make E5 value becomes D5 + 1.

Comment: I copied your script and it didn't work on any of the cells in column D :/

Comment: I changed a condition in if statement e.range.rowStart !=3 to e.range.rowStart < 3. Firstly, it worked only on 3rd row (field D3) now is set to work on all rows from D3 onwards. If you want it to work on every row in D column, you can remove that condition from if statement.